# Skillet cooking Medovik (Russian Honey Cake)?

Tags: cake, frying-pan, honey

Medovik traditionally calls for baking individual pancake shaped layers in the oven. Would frying in a skillet be a workable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently, yes](https://www.lilcookie.com/medovik-crepe-cake/).  What you'll end up with will be a somewhat different texture than traditional medovik, but I bet it'll still be delicious.